# Elasticsearch : MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested:JsonParseException[Un expected character ('}'

Tags: php, json, jdbc, elasticsearch

I am facing issue with JDBC driver using **Elasticsearch**.

I have downloaded the necessary files and it was installed in my htdocs folder.

here is the path i have installed

```
e:\xampp\htdocs\search\elasticsearch-1.7.1
```

i have installed the JDBC plugin in same folder, path is

```
e:\xampp\htdocs\search\elasticsearch-1.7.1\plugins\river-jdbc\
```

and above path has two files

```
1) elasticsearch-river-jdbc-1.0.0.RC1.2.jar
2) mysql-connector-java-5.1.26-bin.jar
```

After the installation i have restarted the elasticsearch.bat in bin folder.

then i have checked the jdbc in below path

```
http://localhost:9200/_nodes?settings=true&pretty=true\
```

i got all the details, here is the plugin node,

```
"plugins": [

     {
        "name": "river-jdbc",

        "version": "NA",

        "description": "JDBC River",

        "jvm": true,
        "site": false

     }
```

i hope the installation was completed. then i have created config.json file in `e:\xampp\htdocs\search\elasticsearch-1.7.1\`
this file contains below codes

```
{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" :{
        "strategy" : "oneshot",
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:9200/dbname",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "",
        "sql" : "select * from tablename",
        "poll" : "1h",
        "scale" : 0,
        "autocommit" : false,
        "fetchsize" : 100,
        "max_rows" : 0,
        "max_retries" : 3,
        "max_retries_wait" : "10s",
        "locale" : "it",
        "digesting" : true,
    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "jdbc",
        "type" : "jdbc",
        "bulk_size" : 100,
        "max_bulk_requests" : 30,
        "versioning" : false,
        "acknowledge" : false
    }
}
```

if i am running the below code

```
E:\Xampp\htdocs\search\elasticsearch-1.7.1>curl -XPUT "http://127.0.0.1:9200/_river/jdbcriver/_meta" -d @config.json
```

it shows below error,

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: JsonParseException[Un
expected character ('}' (code 125)): was expecting either valid name character (
for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name\n at [Source
: [B@458c9675; line: 1, column: 495]]; ","status":400}
E:\Xampp\htdocs\search\elasticsearch-1.7.1>
```

is there anything missing from my end. How can i connect the table and get the results?

Comment: The config file does not seem like valid json it should not have a comma after  `"digesting" : true`

Comment: Thanks it was working now. I got below result `{"_index":"_river","_type":"jdbcriver","_id":"_meta","_version":1,"created":true
}`

Comment: cool should i add it to the answer ?